# How to transport cargo using boats in minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

The new version of Minecraft has added the possibility to travel quickly (40 m/s if I'm correct) by boats that are placed on ice. This is a very effective means of transporting persons, but how to transport cargo using this system?

**Is there any possibility to place chests on or store cargo in boats?**

Answer (score 6):

In a way, but it's a bit of a fuss.

Donkey and mules can have a chest right clicked onto them in order to give them an accessible inventory:

[image: Image of a donkey's inventory]

Adult donkeys can't enter a boat, but they can enter a boat as an baby, then grow up while still inside the boat. So, what you'll need to do is make a baby donkey enter a boat:

[image: Image of baby donkey in boat]

Then wait for it to grow up and add a chest to it:

[image: Image of adult donkey in boat]

Comment: Is it possible to secure the donkeys then by fixing them to the boat using a leash?

Comment: @MedwedianPresident You could have a player riding the boat and holding the lead. Otherwise I don't believe so.

Comment: @colorfusion awwwwww I had an answer prepared :-(